# Как правильно включить в состав программы файлы с данными?

Tags: c#

Чтобы заполнить несколько массивов, сделал текстовые файлы, которые загружаются через
Directory.GetFiles();
Но после создания релиза программы файлы остаются вне файла .exe

Нигде не могу найти ответа на этот вопрос: 
как решить проблему, чтобы данные находились 
внутри .exe, а не в отдельных файлах.

Comment: За ночь ни одного совета. :-(((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте ресурсы: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/7k989cfy%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Спасибо, вот работающий код:

using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

//www.youtube.com/watch?v=ro_4Otm43UE
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {public Form1(){InitializeComponent();}
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){}
        //для картинки
        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.imagename;}

        //для текста
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {richTextBox1.Text = Properties.Resources.textname;}
    }
}